# Scrapy extrae la url parcialmente

Tags: python, url, scrapy, href

Mi araña Scrapy funciona en todo, pero la extracción de la url a través de xpath @href no extrae la url completa, siempre la falta la parte final de la url desde el signo "?......." que marca la variable GET de la url.
¿Sabe alguien si Scrapy tiene algún limite de caracteres o algo así?
Es la primera vez que me pasa, el resto de arañas que lanzo a otras paginas fucnionan perfectamente.
Gracias por las respuestas.

Incluyo el codigo completo de la araña:

```
import scrapy

class autoscouth(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "autoscouth"

    start_urls = [
         'https://www.autoscout24.es/lst/audi?sort=standard&desc=0&offer=J%2CU%2CO%2CD%2CS&ustate=N%2CU&cy=E&atype=C',

        ]

    def parse(self, response):
            # for autos in response.xpath('//div[@class="cl-listing-elements"]/div[@class="cl-ssi-fragment "]/div[@class="cl-list-elements"]'):
            for autos in response.xpath('//*[@class="cldt-summary-full-item"]'):
                    yield  {
                            'url' : 'https://www.autoscouth' + autos.xpath('.//div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a/@href').extract_first(),
                            'marca' : autos.xpath('.//div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a/div[1]/h2[1]/text()').extract_first(),
                            'version' : autos.xpath('.//div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a/div[1]/h2[2]/text()').extract_first(),
                            'combustible' : autos.xpath('.//div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li[7]/text()').extract_first(),                    
                            'precio' : autos.xpath('.//div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/span/text()').extract_first(),
                            'cv' : autos.xpath('.//div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/text()').extract_first(),
                            'km' : autos.xpath('.//div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/text()').extract_first(),
                            'anio' : autos.xpath('.//div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/text()').extract_first(),
                            'ciudad' : autos.xpath('//div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]/text()').extract_first(),
                        }
```

Comment: No, no es normal. Quizás el atributo href sea generado dinámicamente ejecutándose javascript en el navegador, y por tanto no está disponible en el HTML estático que descargas con la araña. ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de un caso concreto para poder hacer alguna prueba?

Comment: `start_urls = [
         'https://www.autoscout24.es/lst/audi?sort=standard&desc=0&offer=J%2CU%2CO%2CD%2CS&ustate=N%2CU&cy=E&atype=C', ]

    def parse(self, response):
            # for autos in response.xpath('//div[@class="cl-listing-elements"]/div[@class="cl-ssi-fragment "]/div[@class="cl-list-elements"]'):
            for autos in response.xpath('//*[@class="cldt-summary-full-item"]'):
                    yield  {
                            'url' : 'https://www.autoscouth' + autos.xpath('.//div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a/@href').extract_first(),
    
                        }`

Comment: Como has podido comprobar, el código en los comentarios no puede formatearse correctamente y es imposible de leer. Por favor, edita la pregunta y añade el código en ella (mira [aqui](https://bit.ly/SOesPASTE) para como pegarlo para que quede bien). De todas formas yo esperaba también una URL real y completa de las que te causa problemas para poder ver yo mismo qué contiene el HTML que extraería la araña.

Comment: He añadido el codigo de la araña en la parte de comentario para que sea legible. Muchas gracias por anticipado por vuestra ayuda!!!

Comment: ¿Qué salida esperabas? Yo he probado a hacer el mismo scraping de esa URL (pero sin usar `scrapy`, sino con `requests` y `lxml` "a pelo") y las URLs que me salen tienen esta pinta: `https://www.autoscouth/anuncios/audi-a4-1-9-tdi-81-kw-110-cv-diesel-verde-093d3e39-9aaf-4f8a-8179-1c366531355e` ¿Es eso lo que esperabas? Porque eso es lo que viene en el HTML recibido, no hay "campo" _query_ ni interrogantes.

Comment: Efectivamente, esa url es la que hay en el HTML, pero si la pruebas no funciona le faltan argumentos, si haces click en la pagina y miras el link de la misma veras que el que ves en el HTML esta incompleto. Por eso estoy viendo que puedo hacer para conseguir la url completa. Gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Pues esto ratifica mi primer comentario. La URL no viene en el HTML sino que es construida dinámicamente cuando el navegador ejecuta el js de esa página. Necesitas entonces cambiar la estrategia de scraping y usar selenium, que permite "operar por control remoto" un navegador real y recuperar el HTML una vez éste lo ha procesado ejecutando su javascript, así como simular acciones de usuario, como hacer clic en elementos concretos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda ¿Que me recomiendas para empezar con Selenium? Donde debo ir a buscar información de calidad???

Answer (score 0):

Prueba

```
'url' : 'https://www.autoscouth' + autos.xpath('.//div[@class="cldt-summary-titles"]/a/@href').extract_first(),
```

no puedo comentar

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/212119)

Comment: pues si provee el código y si me funciono y siendo literales con la pregunta si se respondía... por cierto ya le voy entendiendo a esto de reputación y comentarios gracias por el enlace